# How to save modified buffers when changing desktop?

Tags: desktop

I am using `desktop-save-mode` and `desktop-change-dir` to handle multiple desktops. This works fine, except for the case when I have modified some buffers, and then run `desktop-change-dir` before having saved the changes.

I thought that `desktop-change-dir` would save any buffers before switching desktops, instead I get a question `Buffer <name> modified; kill anyway ? (yes/no)`. (Note that this question is somewhat different from the question you get when killing emacs, in that it does not ask if you would like to save the buffer or not.)

If I type `yes` to the question, the modification to the buffer is lost, if I type `no` the buffer is carried on to the next desktop.
(Neither of these options is desired, so I have to press `C-g` to abort and save the file manually)

Instead I would like to have the modified buffers saved automatically. Is this possible?

Here is a minimal example:

```
$ emacs -Q -l init.el &
```

where `init.el` is:

```el
(defvar my-desktop-dir1
  (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name "desktop1")))

(defvar my-desktop-dir2
  (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name "desktop2")))

(defun my-switch-desktop ()
  (interactive)
  ;; this line is commented out since `desktop-save' should be
  ;; called by `desktop-change-dir'
  ;;(desktop-save my-desktop-dir1 t t)
  (desktop-change-dir my-desktop-dir2))

(require 'desktop)
(setq desktop-path (list my-desktop-dir1))
(setq desktop-save t)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(desktop-read)
```

Comment: as an aside, since you seem to be using multiple desktops and switching from one to another, you might want to try [desktop+](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus): it's a small package that I wrote to do just that. If you like it, I can easily incorporate your `save-some-buffers` solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `save-some-buffers`:

```el
(defun my-switch-desktop ()
  (interactive)
  ;; If save-silently-p is non-nil, saves all the file-visiting buffers
  ;;  without querying the user.
  (let ((save-silently t)) 
    (save-some-buffers save-silently))
  (desktop-change-dir my-desktop-dir2))
```